# how to use a variable created in local scope "without assigning" in global

Tags: php, function, scope, global, local

I'm trying to use a variable created in local scope without assigning that variable in global. Look what I mean :

```
<?
function foo(){
    $bar = inside;
}
foo();
echo $bar; // It will give an error that $bar is not assigned
?>
```

Now you may have understood what I'm trying..? Yes I want to echo that $bar without assigning it in global scope.

Some coding examples are well-honored.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are asking for globals without globals, which is obviously impossible. There is a better way to do what you want to do; tell us what it is.

Comment: I am trying to make a function that makes SQL queries easier which returns the result of query in $result(local). I want to assign that $result to another variable(global) after running function

Comment: **Do not do this. Your code will be horrible.** Do what Quentin suggests, even though it's not what you asked.

Comment: Pretty much this is exactly how $http_response_header works - too bad whoever came up with that didn't get the advice "Don't do this" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only possibly way is to use the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) super-global (at least without returning it):

```
function foo(){
  $GLOBALS['bar'] = 'baz';
}

foo();
echo $bar;
```

Otherwise you're looking at defining it in global scope first, then specifying you need access to it using [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
$bar = null;

function foo(){
  global $bar;

  $bar = 'baz';
}

foo();
echo $bar;
```

---

The better alternative is to use objects where scope remains within the object and you can still retain structure and integrity of code:

```
class Foo
{
  var $bar = null;

  function Bar()
  {
    $this->bar = 'baz';
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->Bar();
echo $foo->bar;
```

Comment: Eh... is this *"without assigning that variable in global"*?

Comment: This is specifically what the OP doens't want to do.

Comment: @Jon/Deleteman: Yes, it defined it in global scope, however so does defining a variable just to assign it a returned value from a function (where do you think `$bar` is defined in Quentin's example?). You have to, at some point, define it there. It's a matter of "pre-defining" that's being alleviated.

Comment: First one example is perfect and that is what i want. Thanks Brad

Answer (score 2):

Use return values.

```
<?php
function foo(){
    $bar = "inside";
    return $bar;
}
$bar = foo();
echo $bar;
?>
```

Comment: I told that I want to use $bar without assigning. You assigned a function to $bar and that's not what I require.

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk — That might have been what you intended to say, but it was vague and open to interpretation. I assumed you meant "without using [the `global` keyword](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)". You cannot use data if it doesn't exist in the scope you want to use it in. That would be illogical and logic is the heart of programming.

Comment: Please tell me about Brad Christie answer. Is there's anything illogical ?

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk — It assigns it to a global supervariable (which is in scope for everything), so it isn't illogical. It is just a practise that leads to code that is horrible to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the content of a local variable from outsite it's content, you have 3 options:

Using a global variable: Not usually recomended and not what you're looking for.

Return the value of that variable:

> ```
> <?
> function foo(){
>     $bar = inside;
> }
> $outisde_bar = foo();
> echo $outside_bar;
> ?>
> ```

Using a referenced variable as an attribute for the function:

> ```
> <?
> function foo(&$bar){
>     $bar = inside;
> }
> foo($bar);
> echo $bar;
> ?>
> ```

Does that help?

Comment: And I'm **positive** neither `$outside_bar` nor `$bar` are defined in global scope in this example, where as my example they clearly are...

Comment: On the third example, the `&amp;` should only be `&` but SO is changing it.

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk Fixed the example, that way you're not avoiding using global variables.